flutter_facbook_auth is showing -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbapi:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.) for iOS
I have implemented Login with Facebook in my Flutter app using
flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.0. It was working perfectly both for Android and iOS. However, all of a sudden the error below is generated only for iOS in real devices.

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbapi:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)" false
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: PlatformException(FAILED, The operation couldn’t be
completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.), null, null)

This is the snippet from my pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # to add facebook login
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.0


Snippet from my info.plist
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    </array>

I have set the global iOS platform to 12.0 in my Podfile.
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

Here is how my AppDelegate.swift file looks:
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


This is the main portion to handle login with facebook method:
final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
        //loginTracking: LoginTracking.limited,
        //nonce: nonce,
        );
    if (loginResult.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      print('................SUCCESS'); // this is successful
      // final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.accessToken!;
      //
      final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();// <-- This is where getting the Error.

Error from the log:

Please, kindly help me solve the issue. Thank you all in advance.

It looks the app that supports that url scheme is not installed kLSApplicationNotFoundErr

How do I solve that? @Paulw11

Install the app it is looking for? Presumably the Facebook app?

The issue was related to the Limited Facebook Login for iOS. The problem has been solved in flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.1 and from this issue: https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/412

I was facing a similar issue on real iOS device. Seems like a solution is to enable login tracking:
FacebookAuth.instance.login(loginTracking: LoginTracking.enabled)

Here is the quote from the link:

I encountered the same issue and discovered that the exception occurs
only when my app has been granted app tracking permission and I use
the default FacebookAuth.instance.login() function. This function uses
the loginTracking parameter with the default value
LoginTracking.limited. When I change the parameter to
LoginTracking.enabled, everything works fine.
Therefore, if you are requesting app tracking permission (common if
you are using ads) and the user has granted the permission, you should
use LoginTracking.enabled.
If you do not want to check if app tracking is enabled, just use:
FacebookAuth.instance.login(loginTracking: LoginTracking.enabled)

Better explanation is given on this link: https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/412
